# installed VS 2003, VS2010 websites will not load without 32bit enabled

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I had to support this application written in 2003 so I installed it on my local computer and now my websites give me the following error when running without 32bit applications installed.

Previously I ran under and app pool without 32bit applications installed.  What could have changed?

ISAPI Filter 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor architecture.... To learn more about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else encounters this... I went to the websites that were having the trouble, then navigated to the ISAPI filter section, and noticed that one of the paths had an extra backslash.

[image]